# GCP unmanaged instance groups in Shared VPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are using GCP with a shared VPC. In one project, we have created a VM and an unmanaged instance group.

In another project we have created a loadbalancer. Is it possible to use the unmanaged instance group from the other project?

Answer (score 1):

The load balancer, the backend service and the Instance Group must be in the same project. The shared VPC shares only the subnet IP range, not the resources created on it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Guillaume. I wanted to create a single loadbalancer in one common service project and then point a domain (e.g. api.company.com) to that loadbalancer. Then I wanted paths /api1, /api2 which would then route to different vms in projects with the shared VPC.  Any idea if there is any other way that I could set this up? I thought zonal NEGs may help if I could use the IP of the VM but that didn't look possible either as it looks like I need to select a VM. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes a zonal NEG could be the solution. I never tried but it's the purpose of the NEG. You might have to create several NEG if you have several zone.

Comment: Hmm it seems that creating a zonal NEG using the console requires you to select a VM instance. As the instance is created in the other project, I can't see the VM. I was hoping to just be able to add the IP and port of the VM.

Comment: Can you try by creating a NEG of [type `non-gcp-private-ip-port`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/network-endpoint-groups/create)? Consider the IP, because out of your project, as out of GCP.

Comment: I dug a little bit and you need an hybrid connectivity to achieve that. You can find a [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/traffic-director/tutorials/network-edge-services-multi-environment) that simulate the on-prem on Google Cloud, and achieve exactly what you want. But it's not so nice... Indeed, you have a pool of VM in the middle that act as proxy with Envoy proxy deployed on it and configured by Traffic director. Woah, a big design for a simple routing problem!

Comment: Thanks. The non-gcp-private-ip-port didn't work, when I tried to create the load balancer with this type of NEG, I got an error saying `A network endpoint group of type NON_GCP_PRIVATE_IP_PORT can only be attached to a backend service of load balancing scheme INTERNAL_SELF_MANAGED.` Not sure if I can get past that. I agree, the hybrid connectivity seems overkill. For now, I'll have to create a specific api domain. I hope this feature gets added in the future, it seem's a common usecase. Thanks for your help Guillaume.

Comment: @Swordfish where you able to get any workaround to achieve this functionality. We also have a similar requirement where we have gke apps running in one project and our load balancer configured in another project.